# Connecting more than one device to a SMPS or battery or DC supply

Tags: power-supply, batteries, switch-mode-power-supply, raspberry-pi, components

Thank you for thinking to answer my question.

First of all what I have.

1. SMPS, (output 24 V 2.5 A)
2. Four devices which requires 24 V 1-2.5 A as input to operate.

Note: current drawn from each device is different; means one device requires 1.5 A and another requires 1 A. Simply voltage is constant ie 24 V and amp is variable.

My question is:

**Can I connect all these 4 devices to a single SMPS or DC output in paralell?**

If yes then no problem.

If no, can you please explain the reason behind saying no.
Does this damage my SMPS or the devices which I connected to it or any other problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

No because the four devices may need 1A each and supply can provide only 2.5A.

Comment: Thankyou for answering. But if I, without having this knowledge (your answer) if I was connected all the 4 devices to same output what was going to happen

Comment: What happens to amp in paralell connection means does it adds up or...

Comment: If each device needs  1 amp the supply would have to provide 4 amps total. It can't do that. It might shut down, it might work for a while and overheat.

Comment: Thankyou "just me" For answering my question.

Comment: Justme is this problem is solved by using a SMPS which gives output of 24volt 5amp Or more

Comment: @Newtoworldofelectrons.: How much is 4*2.5 A?

Comment: It is 10 A greybeard